# Angular Reactive form: Restrict from removing last dynamic control

Tags: angular

I have built an angular reactive form which has the ability to add new and delete new addresses. The remove is adding all fields one by one. What I need is that it should not allow the user to delete last control. So if the last control has records it should remove the content from the array but not the control on the form. How do I achieve that.

I have created a stackblitz to replicate the issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssrpkt

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `removeAddress` function (`app.component.ts`) into:

```
public removeAddress(index: number): void {
    const addressess = this.frmFirm.get('addressess') as FormArray;
    if(addressess.length === 1)
    {
      addressess.reset();
      return;
    }
    addressess.removeAt(index);
}
```